# JSON string with format() keyerror

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to use .format() to concatenate some variables in a json string

```
subscription_info = '{"endpoint":"xxx","keys":{"p256dh":"xxx","auth":"xxx"}}'

send_data = '{"message":"message_test", "subscription_info": {$subscription_info} }'.format(subscription_info=subscription_info)
```

But I'm getting

```
KeyError: '"message"'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you concatenating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double up the outer curly braces to avoid interpreting `message` as a format field:

```
send_data = '{{"message":"message_test", "subscription_info": {subscription_info} }}'.format(subscription_info=subscription_info)
print(send_data)
# {"message":"message_test", "subscription_info": {"endpoint":"xxx","keys":{"p256dh":"xxx","auth":"xxx"}} }
```

And you don't need the `$` in your format string; a valid python indentifier is required if you must use a named field.

Answer (score 1):

You are breaking format rules. Normally when you use format [Python looks for the following](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```
"{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
```

So in your case `"message"` becomes a field_name, since `{` is before it and `:` after it. This obviously doesn't work. The `.format()` method is not meant to be used with complex, nested text structures.

One way is to use [`string.Template` together with `.substitute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) instead:

```
>>> tmpl = string.Template('{"message":"message_test", "subscription_info": {$subscription_info} }')
>>> tmpl.substitute(subscription_info=subscription_info)
'{"message":"message_test", "subscription_info": {{"endpoint":"xxx","keys":{"p256dh":"xxx","auth":"xxx"}}} }'
```

However it also isn't meant to be used with nested text structures.

Since you are using JSON then perhaps you should [parse and serialize the JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) instead. This is the proper way to handle the problem:

```
>>> import json
>>> subscription_info = {"endpoint":"xxx","keys":{"p256dh":"xxx","auth":"xxx"}}
>>> send_data = {"message":"message_test", "subscription_info": subscription_info }
>>> json.dumps(send_data)
'{"subscription_info": {"endpoint": "xxx", "keys": {"auth": "xxx", "p256dh": "xxx"}}, "message": "message_test"}'
```

It is the cleanest and safest method.